# Should I keep the ellipsis in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, syntactic-analysis, ellipses

I was wondering if I am using the ellipsis properly in this sentence. If not, what punctuation should I be using in place of the ellipsis?

> "This trick proved to be difficult at times because, as the years progressed, my tics became more and more obvious . . . People were noticing."

Please include any other advice you have for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an em dash.

> My tics became more and more obvious—people were noticing.

or a colon

> My tics became more and more obvious: People were noticing.

Comment: Current conventions tend not to have a capital letter after the colon.